# Tailwind CSS media queries in a Node JS app fail to work on a mobile device

Tags: css, node.js, media-queries, tailwind-css, ejs

I built the following Node JS app with EJS template and Tailwind CSS.

Live Link: https://film-dash.onrender.com/catalog

[Github](https://github.com/Albertyhu/Film-Dash---Internet-Movie-Database-/tree/main/views)

The media queries work fine on a desktop device. You can resize the window of the app and the media queries will respond correctly.

However, they fail to work in a mobile device.

I'm wondering if anyone here has an idea what is causing this issue and if I should go back to using traditional CSS media queries instead.

Answer (score 0):

I found that the solution to this problem involves two steps:

1.) Put the following meta tag in all of EJS templates being used to render each of the pages:

```
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1, minimum-scale=1" />
```

2.) Redefine the breakpoints of the media queries in tailwind.config.js:

```
theme: {
      extend: {
          screens: {
              'xm': { 'min' : '360px' },
              'sm': { 'min': '640px' },
              'md': { 'min': '768px' },
              'lg': { 'min': '1024px' },
              'xl': { 'min': '1280px' },
              '2xl': {'min': '1536px'}
          }
      },
  },
```